# Calculate TIME Difference in ORACLE for same field in different row with output in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I want to calculate the time "Second row Date/Time(F3)" - "First row Date/Time(F2)", to get the difference time in ORACLE sql.
I tried in my ways to use (extract,to_char)apply in LAG function to subtract the date but i unable to get the output result that i wanted as below. Appreciate if someone can help me on this issue. Thanks.

[The output that i wish to get][2]

```
SELECT stg_rmstmp_cj.ota_activity.ID,
stg_rmstmp_cj.ota_activity.LOT,stg_rmstmp_cj.ota_activity.TYPE,stg_rmstmp_cj.ota_activity.KEY, stg_rmstmp_cj.ota_activity.VALUE,A.DATE,
LAG(stg_rmstmp_cj.ota_activity.DATE) OVER (ORDER BY stg_rmstmp_cj.ota_activity.DATE) -stg_rmstmp_cj.ota_activity.DATE AS Different_time 
FROM stg_rmstmp_cj.ota_activity where A.ID='93K-100';
```

This is my latest encountered new error as below with add in partition but seem like it does solve the issue with attached the screen shot sample:

```
select EQP_ID,LOT_ID,ACTIVITY,ID,
TO_CHAR(MODIFIED_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') dt,
TO_CHAR (DATE '1900-01-01' + ABS ( LAG(MODIFIED_DATE,1)OVER(ORDER BY MODIFIED_DATE) - MODIFIED_DATE), 'HH24:MI:SS')AS diff_withoutpartition,
TO_CHAR (DATE '1900-01-01' + ABS ( LAG(MODIFIED_DATE,1)OVER(PARTITION BY EQP_ID ORDER BY MODIFIED_DATE) - MODIFIED_DATE), 'HH24:MI:SS')AS diff_withpartition
from STG_RMSTMP_CJ.ota_activity where EQP_ID = '93K-P007'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. Here `'1900-01-01'` is dummy for `TO_CHAR` to work correctly.

```
WITH MAIN
     AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('20200515 19:11:54', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') DAT1,
                TO_DATE ('20200515 18:11:54', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') DAT2
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT DAT1,
       DAT2,
       TO_CHAR (DATE '1900-01-01' + ABS (DAT1 - DAT2), 'HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM MAIN
```

Same function with using `LAG`.

```
WITH MAIN
     AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('20200515 19:11:54', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') DAT1,
                TO_DATE ('20200515 18:11:54', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') DAT2
           FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT TO_DATE ('20200514 19:12:54', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') DAT1,
                TO_DATE ('20200514 16:12:54', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') DAT2
           FROM DUAL
           )
SELECT DAT1,
       DAT2,
       LAG(DAT1,1)OVER(ORDER BY DAT1) LAG,
       TO_CHAR (DATE '1900-01-01' + ABS ( LAG(DAT1,1)OVER(ORDER BY DAT1) - DAT1), 'HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM MAIN
```

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, i already tried your method if i assigned the value then it can work, but now i need to subtract the same column but in different row, for example: same column Datetime [2] - Datetime[1]. That's why i using LAG function to calculate the time different, but i dont know how to apply this method into LAG function. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer. @Yong

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, i facing one issue, my calculation is correct at first of 5 rows but after row 6 calculation is not the correct and then next row the calculation is back to correct calculation again.

Comment: Most probably it is because of using lag function. One way or another lag can not find a data before value's itself and taking a null or wrong value. That is why you are facing this issue. You can try putting PARTITION BY statement after OVER( if there are any column that we can use for seperation. Write some sample data which includes your problem and let us have a look.

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, i tried to added PARTITION BY but seem like is it encountered the same issue. I have attached the photo that i query out from the database. Thanks

Comment: The way you share your sample is not good for me. I have to write them one by one to produce a result. Please add it in text format and it is not this question's scope. You can ask in another question @Yong

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, ok, i will ask in new question but sorry may i know what you mean in ' add it in text format'?

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, i already create a new question. Hope you could help me on this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I mean do not share samples in picture format try to share them as just plain text. I see your new question. Let us meet there @Yong

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, i need your help again.

Comment: @Yong fire it as a new question

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, yes its a new question. Unfortunately, i unable to ask a new question. i have been banned by stackoverflow :(

Comment: hi @ismetguzelgun, can you click on this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/274818/213881 , this is my new question. Appreciate if you could help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, i need your help on this issue. Appreciate if you could help me on this . Thank you.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/276176/compare-previous-column-and-current-column-in-oracle-sql-and-do-sum

Answer (score 1):

Date-Date returns number, where 1 is equal to 1 day, so you can easily calculate number of hours, minutes and seconds:

```
Trunc(delta*24) = hours
Mod(trunc(delta*24*60),60) = minutes
Mod(trunc(delta*24*60*60),60) = seconds
```

There is also another simple approach: add delta to any constant Date and use simple to_char. For example: `to_char(date'2020-01-01' + delta, 'hh24:mi:ss')` 
But you will need to add the number of days * 24 to hours, in case of delta>1 day, or use 31st of dec as a constant Date and add 'dd' to the format mask

Comment: Hi @Sayan, but how i apply on my query? and i need to subtract date/time  from column 2 - column 1. Sorry i don't understand what you mean. Im new in oracle.